# font-face not working externally

Tags: html, css, font-face

I am trying to use a custom font which works locally for me, but i need to link it too an external website due to a specific requirement.

But as soon as i test it on my localhost when it is linked to my domain - the fonts dont show up

Im not sure if their is a cross domain issue - but any help would be appreciated cheers

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Wisdom";
    src: url("http://transformer.tamar.com/Santa/726318360-Wisdom-Script.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
     url("http://transformer.tamar.com/Santa/726318360-Wisdom-Script.svg#Wisdom Script AI") format("svg"), 
     url("http://transformer.tamar.com/Santa/726318360-Wisdom-Script.woff") format("woff"),
      url("http://transformer.tamar.com/Santa/726318360-Wisdom-Script.ttf") format("truetype");
}

h3.step {
    font-family: 'Wisdom';
    font-size: 1em;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: check these....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14015068/font-face-works-in-chrome-but-not-ie-or-firefox AND http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616306/css-font-face-absolute-url-from-external-domain-fonts-not-loading-in-firefox

Answer (score 0):

`@font-face` URL's must be relative.

Example:

`src: url("/Santa/726318360-Wisdom-Script.ttf") format("truetype");`

[Extra explanations about Relative URLs](http://www.webreference.com/html/tutorial2/3.html)

Comment: so that means i cant link my fonts externally?

Comment: That means you should have the fonts on your own FTP like you have on a Localhost server.

Answer (score 0):

Font-embedding, that is, the `@font-face` requires the font file to be created on a per-domain basis.

That's because the some fonts might have copyright issues